# Background task timers on iOS

Tags: android, ios, timer, background, background-task

I have an android/winphone application. Small part of app (background broadcastreceiver/task) from time to time (approx 10-15 minutes) checks local file with timestamps and if difference between one of timestamps and current time becomes more than - say - 30 minutes, it shows a notification to a user.

In Android I use AlarmManager.setRepeating(...) to setup periodic check, and to run this setup code I register a BroadcastReceiver on action "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" in Manifest. Or call AlarmManager.cancel(...) and AlarmManager.setRepeating(...) on every launch. This way I may ber sure my timers work.

In Windows Universal I use triggers and background tasks. This works the same way with some limitations.

Now I'm porting my app to iOS, and quick look doesn't give me a way to register a function or class to perform quick checks (mostly less than a second) every 10 minutes while the app itself is not launched, and also I would like to register a function on device boot event. Is it possible? 
Or should I keep my app running in background? I'd prefer not to do so, as my checks are lightweight and rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use background fetch for quick executions.
But there are several disadvantages:

1. Doesn't work in sleep mode.
2. You cannot catch device-launch event.
3. It will be dropped in 30 seconds.

I think in common case this is not analog for `AlarmManager`. Forget about it.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Push notification can be used as a trigger. But, nevertheless, this is a server-side implementation.

In the guide above:

1. Check the box Background fetch in the Background Modes of your app’s Capabilities.
2. Use `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(_:)` to set a time interval appropriate for your app.
3. Implement `application(_:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)` in your app delegate to handle the background fetch.

Your callback event is `performFetchWithCompletionHandler`

Comment: Thank for answer! Background fetch in RW article is limited by 10 minutes - or not? I saw Candy Crush which I believe does the same (as it warns about lives restored, that basically the same timer check I suppose). So it looks like background checks in generable is possible. But then - does such app stay alive in background forever? And what if once in a day I need to dowload 32-byte file with current version number - how should I do this (due to slow/buggy network it should take more than 30 sec, while normally takes a couple)?

Comment: The proccess will be killed by iOS if it executes a lot. I have to tested long-term threads.  I got the same problem: `AlarmManager` is iOS. I decided not to use background fetch for periodic launches in release application for my purposes. But may be you will found a nice implementation for yours.

Comment: But if I will just forget about net queries and only read local file and check my timers - will it work after app process is closed? <1 second each 10 minutes isn't so much. Still not quite understand how does it work, what class/method do you mean when talking about background fetch? beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler?

Comment: @Tertium , updated. In  breif, 30 seconds for each executing. iOS checkshow many seconds your app works in background. That's why `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval` is just a minimum time. It doesn't guarantee that the code will execute each 10 minutes. Just check.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll try. In my case it's more than nothing. Regarding to device launch - it's impossible in general or only for background task?

Comment: No way to check restart state. User have to open the app manually to start fetch event.